# doveadm: Delete messages older than date

Tags: dovecot, maintenance

I've a situation where some users keep very old messages (+5 years) on their mailboxes that are just a waste of space and due to safety reasons should also be deleted.

I find out that I could use `doveadm` for this, however running something like:

```
doveadm expunge -u testuser@sv.dev mailbox INBOX savedbefore 1-Jan-2011
```

Doesn't have any effect. From my understanding email clients mark email for deletion before the `expunge` is run on the server to actually remove them.

How can I mark them for deletion using `doveadm` and then run the `doveadm` command before **or** directly and completely delete them?

Comment: I have valuable 10 yr+ old emails that I will continue to keep; I sure hope you're notifying your users...what is the 'safety' argument?

Comment: @pete management argument. We've a process to stored legally relevant messages in specific IMAP folders, however messages in INBOX, Trash and Sent should be discarded after 5 years...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently my solution was almost right, I can do what I need with:

```
doveadm expunge -u testuser@sv.dev mailbox INBOX SENTBEFORE 1-Jan-2011
doveadm expunge -u testuser@sv.dev mailbox INBOX.Sent SENTBEFORE 1-Jan-2011
doveadm expunge -u testuser@sv.dev mailbox INBOX.Trash SENTBEFORE 1-Jan-2011
doveadm purge -u testuser@sv.dev
```

**Note**: You can replace `-u testuser@sv.dev` with `-A` to target all users on the system.

---

**Extra for WHM/cPanel Based E-Mail Systems:**

If you're running a WHM/cPanel machine you need to update the size of your mail directories manually:

```
/scripts/generate_maildirsize --confirm --verbose account_username
```

Or, for all accounts:

```
/scripts/generate_maildirsize --allaccounts --confirm --verbose
```

Comment: On my system, just running the `expunge` command make all old mails dissapear instantly, didn't need to `purge`